# Structural or Messenger in .net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, mvvm-light

i want to ask about best practice in my case :

suppose i have this kind of code

```
Class BaseClass {
    protected bool CheckResponse(string response) {
        if (response == SomeCondition)
        {
            runErrorMessages();
            return true;
        } 
            return false;
    }
}

Class DerivedClassA {
    ConnectorClass myConnector = new ConnectorClass();
    private void myCommand(string req) {
        string resp = await myConnector.SendDataToServer(req);
        if (!CheckResponse(resp))
            DoSomething1();
    }
}

Class ConnectorClass {
    public async Task<string> SendDataToServer(string req) {
        string resp = await Server.WaitForResponse(req);
        return resp;
    }
}
```

It is better like now or like this one below?

```
Abstract Class BaseClass {
    public BaseClass() {
        Messenger.Default.Register<string>(CheckResponse);
    }

    public abstract callWhateverDeriveWant();

    private void CheckResponse(string response) {
        if (response == SomeCondition)
        {
            runErrorMessages();
        } else
            callWhateverDeriveWant();
    }
}

Class DerivedClassA {
    ConnectorClass myConnector = new ConnectorClass();
    private void myCommand(string req) {
        await myConnector.SendDataToServer(req);
    }

    public abstract callWhateverDeriveWant() {
        callSomething();
    }
}

Class ConnectorClass {
    public async Task SendDataToServer(string req) {
        string resp = await Server.WaitForResponse(req);
        Messenger.Default.Send(resp);
    }
}
```

For your information, there will a lot of derive class that derived from BaseClass, and it's behaviour is similar with DerivedClassA.

Please help me to find out what is the best way i solve my case.

Thanks before.

Comment: Certainly both cases would be better if your method naming was more functional than structural. For example `callWhateverDeriveWant` should be `afterResponseChecked` or something like that.

Comment: sorry for that. What method callWhateverDeriveWant do is do something after i know if the response isn't error response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, the answer to your question depends on the intent of your program. These two cases are not at all logically equivalent.

In your first example, you are checking the response for some condition.  Presumably this is a complicated procedure that belongs in its own method. The way your code is written, the `CheckResponse` takes place in the base class, while the derived classes actually contain the conditional logic statements that process its boolean result.  This would be a good use-case when the `CheckResponse` method is the same across all classes, but what you do with the result differs.

In the second example, your `CheckResponse` method and the conditional logic that uses it exist in the base class, so all uses of both are the same across all instances; you are only calling a method on your derived classes once the conditional logic has been executed.  The derived class has no idea what the result of `CheckResponse` was.

So, which objective are you trying to achieve?

Comment: That's right, actually my CheckResponse is same in all derived class, and all derived class will have similar behaviour.

fyi, what happened here actually if response return some error then it'll show the error message and just back to the apps (not doing anything) and all derived class must do same.

Comment: It makes sense to go with the second option then to avoid multiple duplicated lines of code.